# Why is this Haskell program actually concurrent?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I am learning about simple uses of `forkIO` and `Mvar` from Marlow's book: [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/ch07.html). I the section *MVar as a Container for Shared State* the following code is exposed:

```
-- Creates a new Map within an MVar
new :: IO PhoneBookState
new = do
  m <- newMVar Map.empty
  return (PhoneBookState m)

-- Inserts a Key, Value in the Map, locking the MVar
insert :: PhoneBookState -> Name -> PhoneNumber -> IO ()
insert (PhoneBookState m) name number = do
  book <- takeMVar m
  putMVar m (Map.insert name number book)

-- Retrieves the Map, locking the MVar briefly
lookup :: PhoneBookState -> Name -> IO (Maybe PhoneNumber)
lookup (PhoneBookState m) name = do
  book <- takeMVar m
  putMVar m book
  return (Map.lookup name book)
```

Where `PhoneBookState` holds an `MVar (Map Name PhoneNumber)`. My problem comes in the `main` function

```
main = do
  s <- new
  sequence_ [ insert s ("name" ++ show n) (show n) | n <- [1..10000] ]
  lookup s "name999" >>= print
  lookup s "unknown" >>= print
```

The idea is both lookups happening concurrently, but in such a case, shouldn't it be something like

```
main = do
  s <- new
  sequence_ [ insert s ("name" ++ show n) (show n) | n <- [1..10000] ]
  forkIO(lookup s "name999" >>= print)
  lookup s "unknown" >>= print
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the text doesn't mention those two lookups happening concurrently, it only shows how the functions defined are used to illustrate wrapping immutable structures in mutable variables to achieve mutable state in an IO setting

Comment: The first `main` is not concurrent: it performs the lookups in sequence.

Comment: @chi From the book: _The following example models a phone book as a piece of mutable state that may be concurrently modified and inspected by multiple threads_. I was assuming the `main` to be concurrent, but as @M.Aroosi pointed out, probably the intention is to ilustrate mutable state that _"may be"_ concurrent.

Comment: Yes, that's likely it. The book shows a basic use of `MVar`s in plain sequential code. Then one can add `forkIO`s to make it concurrent. In more complex scenarios, you have many threads taking/putting distinct `MVar`s to synchronize. (Of course, a badly designed program may still even lead to deadlock, starvation, and other "usual" issues in concurrent programming, depending on how the `MVar`s are used.)